# Css grid hover out of area

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Hey guys I'm having a bit of trouble here. When i hover over my images they go out of the area and moves the web page. I was trying to do something more along the lines of [this website](https://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1788?siteId=e5861708-6797-4ea2-9944-153d810bfa05&metaSiteId=7ae43e63-90b0-4043-9d2e-9c2662ffc6c8&originUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fphotography)

Can anyone help with what I'm trying to accomplish and any other tips will be greatly appreciated

[My website](https://codepen.io/brok3ndev/pen/JjoORmW)

**language: lang-css**

```
*{
     margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: black;
}

h1, h2{
    font-family: 'Chilanka', cursive;
}

.firstContainer{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20fr 20fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}



.Nav{
    grid-area: end;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    word-spacing: 20px;
}

.head{
    display: grid;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.firstHeader{
    font-weight: 100;
}

.secHeader{
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.container{
    display: grid;
    margin-top: 80px;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 20vw);
    max-width: 1270px;
}


  .galleryBox img{
    max-width: 100%;
    width:  100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .Imgs{
      background-position: center;
      background-size: 100%;
      transition: 2s;
  }

  img {
    transition: transform .25s ease;
}

  .Imgs:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 16px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

**language: lang-html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa:200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>FirstFloorVisuals</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="head">
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="firstHeader">FirstFloor.Visuals</h1>
        <h2 class="secHeader">Creativty | Design | Visions</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="firstContainer">
    <div class="Nav">
        <a href=" ">Portfolio</a>
        <a href=" ">About</a>
        <a href=" ">Contact</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="Imgs" alt="Image 1">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="Imgs" alt="Image 2">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="Imgs" alt="Image 3">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="Imgs" alt="Image 4">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="Imgs" alt="Image 5">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"  class="Imgs" alt="Image 6">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="Imgs"  alt="Image 6">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"  class="Imgs" alt="Image 6">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"  class="Imgs" alt="Image 6">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="Imgs" alt="Image 6">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="Imgs" alt="Image 6">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="phttps://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="Imgs" alt="Image 6">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="Imgs" alt="Image 6">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="Imgs" alt="Image 6">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="Imgs" alt="Image 6">
            </div>
            <div class="galleryBox">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="Imgs" alt="Image 6">
            </div>
          </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/sparxia/pen/dyPZgeq `.galleryBox {
  overflow: hidden;
}`

Comment: Hey thanks alot that did work. Now my only issue is when you hover over the images sometimes it shows the white background. Any idea why ? @ManojKumar

Comment: Like this? https://prnt.sc/qj69xn

Comment: Whats is that a link of ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all `background-position: center;` and `background-size: 100%;` this both properties are not works with `<img>`. these are the properties which used to set the background image not feature image. so I have remove that from my code given below.

now if you want full-width container then set it's width to 100%.

then set `overflow:hidden` to `galleryBox`(parent box of single image).

for more understanding please review the following snippet.

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.container{
    display: grid;
    margin-top: 80px;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 20vw);
    max-width: 100%;
}
.galleryBox {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.galleryBox img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 2s;
}
.galleryBox img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
  <div class="galleryBox">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557296869-e9a76501a0d1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

I hope this code is useful to you and help you to solve your problem.

Thank you...